# How to display a full width table before the add to cart button in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, html-table, woocommerce-theming

I want to show a full width table data before the add to cart button.

Everything is fine, but it is shown in the second column. Possibly because there are 2 columns. I want to display the table in one column with the full table width and after the table with the default view.

As output first column area is empty and my table showing in 2nd column.

**Current code:**

```php
add_action('woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button','show_product_table');
function show_product_table(){
    global $product;

    ?>

    <style>
.mxtb {
  font-family: verdana, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

.mxtb td , th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

.mxtb tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
</style>

    <h2>Products</h2>

<table class ="mxtb">
  <tr>
    <th>Product</th>
    <th>Grade</th>
    <th>Stock</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Product 1</td>
    <td>A1</td>
    <td>Min 100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Product 2</td>
    <td>A1</td>
    <td>Min 100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Product 3</td>
    <td>A2</td>
    <td>Min 200</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Product 4</td>
    <td>A1</td>
    <td>Min 100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Product 5</td>
    <td>A2</td>
    <td>Min 200</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Product 6</td>
    <td>A1</td>
    <td>Min 100</td>
  </tr>
</table>
    <?php
}
```

---

**Current output:**

[image: Need to add full-width table in the single product page]

**Website URL:** http://testing.rhkshop.in/product/product-3/

Answer (score 0):

**Easiest & Implement and Forgot Way:**

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'woo_new_product_tab' );
function woo_new_product_tab( $tabs ) {
// Adds the new tab
    $tabs['prd_table'] = array(
        'title'     => __( 'Products', 'woocommerce' ),
        'priority'  => 5,
        'callback'  => 'show_product_table'
    );

    return $tabs;
}

function show_product_table(){
    global $product;

    ?>

    <style>
.mxtb {
  font-family: verdana, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

.mxtb td , th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

.mxtb tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
</style>

<table class ="mxtb">
  <tr>
    <th>Product</th>
    <th>Grade</th>
    <th>Stock</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Product 1</td>
    <td>A1</td>
    <td>Min 100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Product 2</td>
    <td>A1</td>
    <td>Min 100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Product 3</td>
    <td>A2</td>
    <td>Min 200</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Product 4</td>
    <td>A1</td>
    <td>Min 100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Product 5</td>
    <td>A2</td>
    <td>Min 200</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Product 6</td>
    <td>A1</td>
    <td>Min 100</td>
  </tr>
</table>
    <?php
}
```

1. Add the filter `woocommerce_product_tabs` and hook the tab generation function `woo_new_product_tab`
2. Push your tab configuration array (which is self-explanatory) into the hook function argument `$tabs`
3. Finally, return the argument `$tabs`

Lets we explore our newly pushed associative array `prd_table` and its value:

1. The associative key `prd_table` will be used as a class reference in our frontend tab element
2. The key `title` will be rendered as the title of the tab in the frontend
3. We set `priority` to `5` lowest the priority it displays it in the very first (lower the priority number which renders earlier in the tab section else if the number is higher then it will render later)
4. The key `callback` refers to the callback function
5. Here we assigned `callback` key's value as `show_product_table` which calls your custom function beneath the hook function declaration

**How It Looks:**

[image]

---

**Cumbersome & Prolonged Maintenance Way:**

To accomplish your desired changes you have to override the template but there is an intricacy when you add the table data just above the add to cart button. But you can override the template by following the procedure explained in this [tutorial](https://www.vijayan.in/woocommerce-theme-overriding/).

And you have to override the following template in your theme (I'm explained using the WooCommerce plugins default template which is applicable to all overridden themes).

1. `single-product.php` (which renders the partial template `content-single-product.php` using the woo function `wc_get_template_part`)
2. If you further go down and glanced over the file `content-single-product.php` you will find the line `<div id="product-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php wc_product_class( '', $product ); ?>>` which is enclose the product image and summary
3. The product summary is enclosed in the div tag `<div class="summary entry-summary">` i.e. the things which are rendered right side of the product image
4. If you just noted a few lines above that summary div tag you will find the line `do_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary' );` which execute all the hooks hooked to this action
5. If you searched you project directory with the search term `woocommerce_before_single_product_summary` (Actually in WooCommerce official developer commented what are the function hooked to this action. Some custom themes may miss that's why I suggested you to search the complete project directory)
6. Which will redirect us to the helper file `wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-template-hooks.php` to the line `add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_show_product_images', 20 );`
7. If you noted this calls the function `woocommerce_show_product_images` which is in the file `wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-template-functions.php`
8. That function declaration is

   `function woocommerce_show_product_images() {
     wc_get_template( 'single-product/product-image.php' );
   }`
9. Which fetch the template in the path `single-product/product-image.php` which is in the following relative path `wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/single-product/product-image.php` in WooCommerce plugin
10. Hope you understand the structural flow if you really need to override this please understand how these templates are glued together and override it to your desired way
11. This way of customization you do will result in prolonged customization as the theme provider updates the template you have to update again

So the mainly involved templates are one main template:

`wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/single-product.php`

And two partial templates are:

1. `wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/content-single-product.php` for product summary i.e. right side column
2. `wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/single-product/product-image.php` for product image i.e. left side column

Comment: Great information about custom tabs, wrapped elements in tabs and handling templates. But this is not a my solution or answer! I asked for show table in single product summary before add to cart button as I provided screenshot. Now I changed in css before you answer so output is different vs link and screenshot.

Comment: After adding css it's ok now, but still not exactly what I want! I need to keep image left side in first column as default, product title and price meta should be in right column as default. My product table should be above in murged with 2 columns with full width.

Comment: Share the wireframe of how you expect

Comment: Add the sample screen as expected output in the question